# Simplifying a factor of a factored polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In the following complicated example, Mathematica fails to simplify the x-1

```
pol = (-1 + x) (2 Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[f, 1] + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(2\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(1\)]\) + 2 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[f, 2] + 
    Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[f, 2] + 
    2 Subscript[d, 2] Subscript[e, 1] x - 
    2 Subscript[d, 2] Subscript[e, 2] x - 
    Subscript[c, 1] Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 2] x + 
    Subscript[c, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(2\), \(2\)]\) x + 
    2 Subscript[f, 1] x + Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[f, 1] x + 
    2 Subscript[f, 2] x + 2 Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[f, 2] x - 
    Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[f, 2] x + 
    Subscript[c, 1] Subscript[e, 1] x^2 + 
    Subscript[d, 2] Subscript[e, 1] x^2 - 
    Subscript[c, 1] Subscript[e, 2] x^2 - 
    Subscript[d, 2] Subscript[e, 2] x^2 + 2 Subscript[f, 1] x^2 + 
    Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[f, 1] x^2 + 2 Subscript[f, 2] x^2 + 
    Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[f, 2] x^2)
pol2 = pol/(1 - x) // Simplify
```

It does manage if I erase may of the terms of the second factor. I fail to see what goes wrong with the long version

Comment: First of all, as far as I know, using `Subscript` is not the way to go. Aside of that, with what exactly do you want to simplify the overall `-1+x`? You have `-1+x` times a thing. Are you sure that you can factor `1/(-1+x)` within the remaining thing to cancel the one sitting in front?

Comment: How about `pol2 = (pol/(1 - x)) //Expand//Simplify` ?

Comment: Thanks @BabaYaga, this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use side relation, like this

```
pol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now if you just use Simplify, it will not do it, due to sign difference. It is picky I guess:

```
Simplify[pol/(1 - x)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change it to

```
Simplify[pol/(1-x),{whatever==1-x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option is to just do

```
pol/(-(1-x))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No need for Simplify at all.

**Update**

Another option is `Cancel`

```
pol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cancel[pol/(1-x)]//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @Nasser, this works, but I do not understand the whatever== syntax. Any reference?

Comment: @florin I do not know where the documentation  for side relation is. But all what it does is replaces `1-x` with a single name of your choosing.  I choose whatever, but you can use `a` or `b`. using side relation now your expression can be simplified more easily, since `1-x` is single name instead of compound expression.  If you google **mathematica simplify side releation** you will see more examples.